# Live DVD single user mode

Tags: livedvd, live-environment

I am tying to boot into single user mode using a live dvd, but i have had little luck, i heard that i should hold down the shift key during start up but it gave some messages then it continued to boot into the desktop mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quickly press the Shift key or Escape, as soon as the bios finishes.  That  will bring up Grub menu

[image]

Once you get the menu shown below, you can drop to root prompt, so you can do some maintenance, or any of the other choices.
[image]